# How to give dynamic name to file which is used as source file in macro?

Tags: excel

Daily I run a text file using an Excel macro. However, I want to rename this file every day as "aa". unless I give this name properly macro will not work.

I have mentioned here with the original file name. Note, only this file date is changed day to day.

Filename: 20017122018.ASCII.TXT

The given name is changed day to day as mentioned below.

```
20017122018.ASCII.TXT

20118122018.ASCII.TXT 

20219122018.ASCII.TXT 

20320122018.ASCII.TXT
```

### Update

This is my recorded macro code. How can I correct this? I want to replace aa.txt by standard file name.

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;D:\aa.txt", Destination _
    :=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "aa"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(9, 2, 9, 1, 2, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 1, 9, 1, 9, 1, _
    9)
    .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(4, 16, 7, 6, 16, 8, 4, 12, 3, 12, 3, 25, 13, 3, 4, 13, 1 _
    , 1, 6, 7, 3)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Cells.Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$828").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="144"
Range("G54").Select
```

Comment: So the VBA code is expecting a file called `aa.txt`?  Do you only have a single text file each time?  Also could we see the code you're using at the moment so we can see how any new code will fit into the existing code.

Comment: Yes VBA code is expecting a file called aa.txt and there is only one file for each time. I want to give the standard file name instead of aa.txt but each time VBA should identify the file when front 3 digit and date changing. Rest of the details as normal mentioned in the below. ASCII.TXT this doesnt change. NOTE this is a recorded macro.

Comment: _Rest of the details as normal mentioned in the below_ What is normal?  Easier if you post the code you're currently using.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

This code will display only the `*.ASCII.txt` files in the selected folder.
Select the file you want and it will open it.

This tells it to show the files that are in the same folder as the Excel file:

```
vFile = GetFile(ThisWorkbook.Path)
```

This tells it to show the files that are in the *Default file location*:

```
vFile = GetFile()
```

You then reference the text file using `wrkBk`.

This is the whole procedure:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim vFile As Variant
    Dim wrkBk As Workbook

    vFile = GetFile()

    If vFile <> "" Then
        Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open(vFile)
    End If

End Sub

Function GetFile(Optional startFolder As Variant = -1) As Variant
    Dim fle As FileDialog
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Set fle = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fle
        .Title = "Select a File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "ASCII.TXT", "*.ASCII.txt", 1
        If startFolder = -1 Then
            .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        Else
            If Right(startFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
                .InitialFileName = startFolder & "\"
            Else
                .InitialFileName = startFolder
            End If
        End If
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        vItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFile = vItem
    Set fle = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I would make `GetFile` the following way: `Function GetFile(ByRef strFilePath) As Boolean`. This way the using of this function is much cleaner: `If Not GetFile(vFile) Then Exit Sub`.

Comment: @JohnyL At the moment `GetFile` holds the path of the file to open, changing it to a `Boolean` would lose that path and I'd have to hold it in a second passed argument or in a global variable. I also wouldn't use `Exit Sub` within an `IF` statement - safer to move execution to the end of the procedure so any tidying up can be performed before exiting and there's only one exit point for the procedure.

Comment: I guess you didn't understand my point :) Here's [clarification](https://pastebin.com/pmRwEGvk)

Comment: @JohnyL Sorry, haven't had a chance to check the code in the link - looked at it last night (couple of bits I wanted to check), but no access to Excel and this morning the sites blocked where I am.

Comment: OK! When you have time, take a look. I am here 

Comment: With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;D:\aa.txt", Destination _
        :=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "aa"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True      THIS IS THE RECORDED MACRO CODE. PLEASE GIVE UPDATE TO THIS. NOTE THIS IS WORKING PROPERLY. BUT I WANT TO GIVE THE STANDARD NAME INSTEAD OF AA.TXT

Comment: Could you add any extra information to your original post please - the edit button is just under the tags.  On first glance - it hasn't got a procedure header (`Sub Import()` or similar) it starts with a `With` but there's no `End With`.  Have you tried the code I posted?